# How do you indicate/request the deletion of an object property in a REST patch

Tags: rest

Is there a standardized way to indicate a null value for a field/parameter in a RESTful PATCH request?

Let's say I have an object, and I want to just flat out remove a property from the object and persist that change to the MT/DB. On the client side, I would just delete the property (in JS), but when PATCHing to my REST API layer, is there a standardized way to indicate that the property (not the object, just the property) should be deleted?

For the sake of clarity/example, here is a hypothetical PATCH route for the object:

```
PATCH /service/thing/{id}
```

and some sample PATCH payloads:

single property update:

```
{ "myprop": "changed" }
```

multi-property update:

```
{ "myprop": "changed", "anotherprop": "changed" }
```

For a PATCH where you want to get rid of `"myprop"` you obviously can't just submit this payload:

```
{ }
```

Would you do something like:

```
{ "myprop": undefined }
```

or, would you create a whole new DELETE route:

```
DELETE /service/thing/{id}/myprop
```

or, something else?

Comment: I used this before and it was "myprop" : null

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would implement `PATCH` just like you propose. In a way that accepts partial representation for update.

This way I would send always the `JSON` partial representation.

```
PATCH { "myprop": "newvalue" }
```

And for deletion of the `myprop` the empty value. Sending back the empty value when requesting a `GET` is up to you. You can always ignore `null` values (which is not the same as empty).

```
PATCH { "myprop": null }
```

Note `null` rather than `undefined`. `null` is a `JSON` value.
But this is just my 2cents.

Comment: What do you mean by "empty value"? I don't know of a JSON value called "empty value"